# WinSock rehost on same port not working properly C++

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, winsock

I've got a program and it's listening on port 200. After a client is connected to it, all the received data from client is written to std::cout. If any error occures while getting data from client, I would like to restart hosting.

```
ServerSocket sock;
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        uint8 buff[1000];
        std::cout << "hosting..." << std::endl;
        sock.Host(port);

        while(true)
        {
            size_t ret = sock.GetData(buff, 1000);
            buff[ret] = '\0';
            std::cout << buff << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch(const SocketException& se)
    {
        std::cout << se.What() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The first time I connect to this everything is fine. If I close the client a SocketException occures (and therefore new hosting begins).

the host function:

```
    m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

m_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
m_address.sin_port = htons(port);
m_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

int optval = 1;
setsockopt(m_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&optval, sizeof(int));

int retval = bind(m_socket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&m_address), sizeof(m_address));

if(retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
    throw SocketException("bind() error", __FUNCTION__, WSAGetLastError());

retval = listen(m_socket, SOMAXCONN);

if(retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
    throw SocketException("listen() error", __FUNCTION__, WSAGetLastError());

m_socket = accept(m_socket, NULL, NULL);

if(m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    throw SocketException("accept() error", __FUNCTION__, WSAGetLastError());
```

I need the setsockopt line becouse I'd like to bind instantly after an error (and the last hosting socket is in TIME_WAIT state?). Without setsockopt I've got bind() errors.
So I use setsockopt and it let's me host on the port without problem. However when I start the client again, and try to connect to the host **no error occures** and I can send data again.
However the program **does not accept any incoming connections** (it's still stuck at accept(m_socket, NULL, NULL); line waiting for incoming connection). I assume that the client can connect somehow to the old socket. Is that possible?

(note:
If I add WSACleanup();
     WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &m_wsaData);
lines to the host function, then **everything is working** as intended. I have no idea why.
WSACleanup();WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &m_wsaData); helps me out only in my example program I made to investigate this issue. In the original program that 2 lines is not working.)

Comment: Are you creating a socket on the client afresh (i.e. call `socket`) after the failure before issuing `connect`? You also need to make sure you are closing a socket with error (both on server and client).

Comment: I close the entire client program (client.exe) and start it again. It manages to connect also manages to send data. (But to the wrong socket if it's possible. And yes I close the socket in the client.exe aswell, no idea if it matters or not if I close it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `bind()` and `listen()` for each connection. You should do `bind()` and `listen()` once when your server starts, and then call only `accept()` repeatedly.

Also to do it properly you should spawn a new thread for each `accept()` call, otherwise people will be able to DOS your server by just opening a connection to it and then not sending anything.

Comment: Exactly what I should have done! Also thank you for the warning on threading issue.